# SIM5360 SPI communication

Tags: spi

I am using a SIM5360 and works very well for GPS and GSM communications. Now I am using the SPI too: I have the SPI activated (AT+CGFUNC) and configured (I following the SPI application note). But, when I send a command (only been tested with write commands) I have always 3bytes with 0x00 after addres and before the data that I want transmit.

Someone have the SPI communication working fine in a SIM5360 module?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like padding, since the max. transfer size is 4 bytes. I assume you mean that the receiving side sees `0x000000bb` when you send data `bb`. It may be that you transfer unit is set to 32 bits i.e 4 bytes. You can check with `AT+ CSPISETPARA?`.

If that's the case, you can try changing it with `AT+ CSPISETPARA =8,0,1` which means you'll only send 8 bits when transferring byte-sized data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the cspisetparam ok, for 8 bits. I following the application note for SPI communication in SIM5360. I tried with 8, 16 and 32 bits bit I have always the 0x00... this is very strange. I am using the EVB and I have Uart2 disabled and the CP2103 in reset...

Comment: @user146886 EVB? UART2? CP2103? You need to give better details.

Comment: Maybe you can try messing with the last parameter i.e. packing data from the output buffer. Try `AT+ CSPISETPARA =8,0,0` instead.